# Calculating and displaying infomation sliced from a text file

Tags: python, slice

I would like to ask for help on what is the best way to calculate and display information sliced from a text file.  The information in the text file looks like this:  John, 90, 87, 98    It contains a name and 3 test scores.  I have to display the information on a line for each person including the average of the grades.  I have been at this for days with very little progress.  I have tried loading the information into a list.  However, I haven't been able to convert the grades into integers.  What would be the best method to accomplish the desired results?  Also, how would I convert the grades to integers so I can calculate the average.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems. Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details.

Answer (score 0):

Use int.

```
with open("myfile") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        row = line.split(",")
        name = row[0]
        scores = [int(e.strip()) for e in row[1:]]
        print "Name: {}\nAverage: {}".format(name, sum(scores)/float(len(scores)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This definitely helps a lot because I just couldn't figure out how to do this.  How would I print the name, 3 scores and average on the same line?  That was another problem I just couldn't figure out.

Comment: @Mike Change the format call. For example`print "{} {}".format("".join(row), sum(scores)/float(len(scores)))`

Comment: Thank You.  It now prints the name and scores on the same line.  However, the average is on a new line.  How would I adjust the format so it lines up with the headings?  This is the output I get . ___________________________________________
Student Name     Score 1     Score 2     Score 3     Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Dave 82 91 77
 83.33333333333333
Tom 79 22 84
 61.666666666666664
Dick 67 96 91
 84.66666666666667

Comment: @Mike. There's probably a trailing newline in final entry of row. You could strip entries earlier `row = [e.strip() for e in line.split(",")]` then `print "{} {} {}".format(name, " ".join(row[1:]), sum(scores)/float(len(scores)))`

Comment: Thank You! You were right and the last code you sent worked great.